# Call background Service every 15 seconds using Broadcast Receiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I try to send data to server every 15 seconds so i used broadcast receiver and Android service but it did not work any more.I check Internet Connection Every 15 second and when connection is available it send data to server.

Test.java

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {
   private Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        this.context = this;
        Intent alarm = new Intent(this.context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        boolean alarmRunning = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 0, alarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
        if(alarmRunning == false) {
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 0, alarm, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 15000, pendingIntent);
        }

    }
```

AlarmReceiver.java

```
    public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent background = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
        context.startService(background);
    }
}
```

BackgroundService.java

```
    public class BackgroundService extends Service {
    private boolean isRunning;
    private Context context;
    private Thread backgroundThread;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        this.context = this;
        this.isRunning = false;
        this.backgroundThread = new Thread(myTask);
    }

    private Runnable myTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           // Do something here
           internet();
           System.out.println("call every 15 seconds");
           Log.d("Background","Services run every 15 second");
           stopSelf();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        this.isRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (!this.isRunning) {
            this.isRunning = true;
            this.backgroundThread.start();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void internet() {
        Helper hp = new Helper(context);
        if (hp.isonline() == true) {
            System.out.println("net connect");
        } else {
            System.out.println("net not available");

        }
    }

    }

}
```

Manifest.xml

```
   <service android:name=".service.BackgroundService" />
        <receiver android:name=".service.AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
```

hole code return in logcat print message only one time, not every 15 seconds.

Comment: Are you trying to send new data every 15 seconds or retrying sending the same data every 15 seconds until the server is available?

Comment: yes i send new data to server every 15 second when phone is connected to internet